# Openlayers icon positioning

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to position a icon in an existing polygon in Openlayers.

I am using the extent of the polygon to find it's center:

```
extent.getCenter(feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
```

and then setting the markers position on the map to be that.

It works if the polygon is relatively simple in it's shape. However for some more advanced polygons the icon seems to be placed outside of the polygon.

In this picture:

[image]

I have marked the big "triangle"'s icon and label with a dark circle.

The label seems to know how to sit inside the polygon, but the icon does not, probably because the label position is calculated internally in Openlayers.

The label is set by defining a style on the label as a Text object. It is possible to define an image in the style too but unfortunately it is placed outside the polygon as well.

Is there any way to get the icon to be positioned where the label is or just somehow to get it to always be inside the drawn polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `getInteriorPoint` method from `ol.geom.Polygon`. See the API for the details http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon-Polygon.html#getInteriorPoint`

You can also see [a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/32mnjk331) illustrating "it works" using a "moon" shaped polygon. Normally, a centroid should be outside of this type of shape whereas with the function, the point returned is inside.

Comment: does this method only exist in the newest openlayers 5?
I am currently running openlayers 4, but if it's a feature of openlayers 5 I will have to upgrade to 5.

Comment: Already here in v4.6.5 API e.g http://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html#getInteriorPoint

Comment: Thanks. I had a slightly more complicated challenge than I described as I have a whole set of features in the layer of various types. getInteriorPoint only exists on Polygons and MultiPolygons. Feature.getGeometry() returns the abstract Geometry type which does not have the getInteriorPoint method.

I solved this simply by performing a cast to a Polygon and checking if the method is there, and otherwise just using the getExtent() as I did before since it is not a Polygon anyway.

Comment: No need to cast, you just need to make something like `if (feature.getGeometry()  instanceof ol.geom.Polygon || feature.getGeometry()  instanceof ol.geom.MultiPolygon) {/*use getInteriorPoint*/} else {/*use your other method*/}`